# SSIS - Setting a Connection String using an variable, but when the variable changes the Connection String doesn't

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, expression

I have fourteen databases that are identically organized and I'm trying to combine them. I extract a list of the databases from a spreadsheet, create connection strings out of them, and then put them into an variable of type "object" called OBJ_Data_Sources. I then have a Foreach Loop Container which loops through the object, putting the connection string into a string variable called "STR_Connection_String."

I clicked on my ODBC connection manager, clicked on expressions, and set ConnectionString to @[User::STR_Connection_String]. The current ConnectionString field is blank and I've set DelayValidation to True so that won't bring up an error.

When I run the package, it properly connects to the first database, but then, for each database in OBJ_Data_Sources, it still only connects to that first database. I know that STR_Connection_String is changing every loop because I used a script task to display its value each time through.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. What am I missing?

Comment: This is my first question on stackoverflow. Mind explaining why the -1 so I know what to do different?

Comment: This still an issue?

Comment: @billinkc I've made progess, sort of, and I just posted a new question about it one minute before you commented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612381/ssis-connection-manager-not-using-the-connectionstring-value

Comment: Right, I started with that one and then decided to see if I could find any background on what you're doing ;)

Comment: @billinkc I'm still new to stackoverflow. Any suggestions or questions? Should I post more information somewhere?